# Ansible not removing directory

Tags: linux, file, directory, ansible

I'm trying to use the `absent` state from Ansible 2.0.0.2 to clean some cache directories from my application and it's not working well. Check the error below:

```
fatal: [my target IP goes here]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": 
true, "msg": "rmtree failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/path/to/my/app/caches/tmp/whatever.tmp'"}
```

This is the "file" line from the playbook:

```
file: dest=/path/to/my/app/caches/tmp state=absent
```

I could use some shell module and put some rm here and there but i would like to be that "good practices" guy.

Any thoughts? :)

Comment: I'm confused, because the path in your error message is completely different from the path in your `file` task.  Could you maybe edit this question to include the *actual* task from your playbook and the *actual* error message?  The mismatch makes it unclear what's going on.

Comment: Sure. Done. Basically, ansible is telling me that there's some file inside the tmp directory that still or not exists. But the point is, i don't want it to stop the removing process and just delete everything inside the caches directory. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Is there anything notable about the file that is triggering the error?  E.g., is it a broken symlink, or something other than a regular file?  Also, which version of Ansible are you using?  Also also, have you considered simply `command: rm -rf /path/to/my/app/caches/tmp`?

Comment: ansible 2.0.0.2
Nothing special, just a jar file from the jboss app.

Comment: Can you include in your question the output of `ls -l /path/to/my/app/caches/tmp/whatever.tmp` after the Ansible run completes?

Comment: Yes, i'm using a simple rm command now, but the message "[WARNING]: Consider using file module with state=absent rather than running rm" is annoying me heh.

Comment: You can [disable those warnings](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#command-warnings) in your `ansible.cfg` if you would like.  The reason I ask for the `ls` output is that, looking at the code for `rmtree`, you could get that error if that file was deleted (a) after the code notes the filename but (b) before the code actually deletes it.

Comment: Just tried the ls: `No such file or directory`

Comment: That seems to confirm my theory.  I think just using `rm -rf` is really the best solution here.

Comment: I'll keep using it, it's working, i appreciate your time!

Answer (score 4):

For posterity:

It looks as if the error...

```
fatal: [my target IP goes here]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": 
true, "msg": "rmtree failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/path/to/my/app/caches/tmp/whatever.tmp'"}
```

...is probably cropping up because the file is getting deleted between (a) python getting a list of files in the directory and (b) actually trying to delete the files.  If you look at the code, Ansible deletes directories by calling `shutil.rmtree`, which does this:

```
  try:
      names = os.listdir(path)
  except os.error, err:
      onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  for name in names:
      fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
      try:
          mode = os.lstat(fullname).st_mode
      except os.error:
          mode = 0
      if stat.S_ISDIR(mode):
          rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
      else:
          try:
              os.remove(fullname)
          except os.error, err:
              onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
```

If the file were deleted between the call to `os.listdir` and the call
to `os.remove`, you would get the `No such file or directory` error.

The solution here is probably just to use `rm`:

```
command: rm -rf /path/to/my/app/caches/tmp
```

An alternative solution would be to patch Ansible such that one could set the `ignore_errors` parameter on `shutil.rmtree`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note - also for posterity. In general, it is not always correct to delete directories that are in use. It should be avoided if possible.

I've just run into a similar situation where the playbook stops a service and wipes its work directory, but for some reason the service reports successful ending prematurely, before it has actually stopped.

This results in the following failure:

```
TASK [test : Stop the service] 
**************************************
changed: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]

TASK [test : Wipe the service directory] 
**********************************
fatal: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "rmtree failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/service/workdir/process.pid'"}
```

This means, that the `.pid` file was deleted after the service has returned successful `stopped` status, when the file tree was already being deleted.

To prevent this from happening I just added the following task in between:

```
- name: Wait for the .pid file to disappear
  wait_for:
    path: '{{ service_workdir }}/service.pid'
    state: 'absent'
    timeout: 10
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the reason of this error is some unexpected runtime changes on the directory that you want to remove, you can consider adding retries to the task.

```
- file: dest=/path/to/my/app/caches/tmp state=absent
  register: delete_folder
  retries: 5
  delay: 2
  until: delete_folder is success
```